# Searching for a formula to replace loop

Tags: javascript, math, recurrence

Is there a simple formula to calculate this?

```
var quantity = 10
var starting_price = 10

var cost = 0
var price = starting_price
for (var n=1; n<=quantity; n++) {
    cost += price
    price += price * 0.01
}

console.log('final price: '+price)
console.log('total cost: '+cost)
```

So 1 would cost 10, 2 would cost 20.1, 3 would cost 30.3, 4 would cost 40.6, 5 would cost 51.  Is there a simple formula I could use to calculate this instead of doing a loop?

Comment: Calculate what? Your calculations are based off a loop incrementing the variable?

Comment: Updated the question to make more sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such question can always be asked to Wolfram Alpha:

> For **price(n)**:
>
> Question: [f(0) = 10, f(n) = f(n-1) + f(n-1) * 0.01](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=f%280%29%20=%2010,%20f%28n%29%20=%20f%28n-1%29%20%2b%20f%28n-1%29%20*%200.01)
>
> Answer: f(n) = 10^(1-2n) 101^n

> For **cost(n)**:
>
> Question: [g(n) =10^(1-2n) 101^n, f(0) = 0, f(n) = f(n-1) + g(n-1)](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=g%28n%29%20=10%5E%281-2n%29%20101%5En,%20f%280%29%20=%200,%20f%28n%29%20=%20f%28n-1%29%20%2b%20g%28n-1%29)
>
> Answer: f(n) = 10^(3-2n) 101^n - 1000

Translated to JavaScript:

```
function price(n) {
    return Math.pow(10, 1 - 2*n) * Math.pow(101, n);
}

function cost(n) {
    return Math.pow(10, 3 - 2*n) * Math.pow(101, n) - 1000;
}
```

The name of such a formula is [recurrence equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation), you learn it e.g. in your first semesters as a CS undergraduate. It's quite easy to do "manually" after a solving a few examples.

---

After OP's change:

> For **price(n)**:
>
> Question: [f(0) = c, f(n) = f(n-1) + f(n-1) * d](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=f%280%29%20%3D%20c%2C%20f%28n%29%20%3D%20f%28n-1%29%20%2B%20f%28n-1%29%20*%20d)
>
> Answer: f(n) = c * (d+1)^n     where c = 10, d = 0.01

> For **cost(n)**:
>
> Question: [g(n) =c (d+1)^n, f(0) = 0, f(n) = f(n-1) + g(n-1)](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=g%28n%29%20%3Dc%20%28d%2B1%29%5En%2C%20f%280%29%20%3D%200%2C%20f%28n%29%20%3D%20f%28n-1%29%20%2B%20g%28n-1%29)
>
> Answer: f(n) = c/d ((d+1)^n - 1)

To see if both results are the same:

> Question: [c/d ((d+1)^n - 1) = 10^(3-2n) 101^n - 1000 where c = 10, d = 0.01](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=c%2Fd%20%28%28d%2B1%29%5En%20-%201%29%20%3D%2010%5E%283-2n%29%20101%5En%20-%201000%20where%20c%20%3D%2010%2C%20d%20%3D%200.01)
>
> Answer: True

Comment: Thanks!  But it looks like the formula changes if the starting price changes.  I updated my question so that it makes more sense.

Comment: You didn't bother to look at Wolfram Alpha, did you? I updated my answer.